# Is anyone else having trouble accessing this site?

Tags: discussion

[image]I have been having trouble accessing the site every day.  I have checked other browsers, cleared my cache and the issue still occurs.  My main browser is Chrome.  I typically get in to the site very late in the evening (after 10p - DST time zone) or in the middle of the night (1a-3a).  The screenshot is below.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: @Marna - What time zone and how do you define "trouble?" What is happening? Do you get a 404 error? do you have a screen shot? More details will help us diagnose for you.

Comment: @Mike - My time zone is DST.  I do not get a 404 error, I just can't access the site.

Answer (score 2):

Next time it happens try checking a service which tests to see if the site's up, such as [IsUp.Me](http://www.isup.me/wordpress.stackexchange.com). You may also which to try a different browser, in my experience Chrome gives up much quicker on connecting to sites. If WordPress.SE keeps failing regardless of browser and IsUp.Me (or another similar service) shows that the site is up, then I'd guess your ISP's DNS servers are having issues. In which case, you might want to try a 3rd party DNS server such as [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/start/).

Comment: Thank you.  Hopefully I will not have an opportunity to test your suggestions (which would make me very happy).  But I appreciate the info, and will let you know the results.

Comment: Open DNS has built in content filters. [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/intl/de/speed/public-dns/) is not that prude. :)

Comment: @toscho: I believe [the Open DNS content filters are off by default](http://www.opendns.com/support/article/226), they are only enabled for phishing sites.

Comment: @Jan Fabry Some filters are [always on](http://forums.opendns.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=158).

Answer (score 0):

We tried to write a canonical article on "why can't I get to this website?" at

https://superuser.com/questions/231977/how-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user

Can you give that a shot?

---

And yes, it *would* be ironic if you couldn't get to Super User either.. so here's a link from Google Cache

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2F231977%2Fhow-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user

and from Coral Cache

http://superuser.com.nyud.net/questions/231977/how-do-i-diagnose-not-being-able-to-reach-a-specific-website-as-an-end-user